# Difference between OSX window's red dot close button and a tabbed window's x close button being pressed?

Tags: macos

Has anyone figured out how to differentiate between a press on the red dot close button and a press on a tabbed window's X close button in macOS? In Apple's documentation every method and member of the tabbing class says "*No overview available*.". Spelunking through the header files did not turn up anything useful.

When an app is configured to terminate when the last window is closed using `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed`, and a single window with multiple tabs is remaining and the user clicks the red close button there appears to be no difference between pressing the red dot and an X on a tabbed window. A `windowShouldClose` message is posted to the delegate but there does not seem to be a way to differentiate if it was the red dot pressed or an X on a tab. Pressing on the red dot will close all the tabs, but there seems to be no way to tell it was the red dot because the OS starts closing tabs and the tabs receive a `windowShouldClose` as well. This makes trying to save the state of the open tabs appear impossible, because the OS closes all the tabs - and by the time `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed` is called, all of the windows are gone.

It gets weirder. Looking at the pointer for the red dot button window (`_redCloseButton = [_ourWindow standardWindowButton:(NSWindowCloseButton)]`), it changes to reflect whichever tab is in front so hooking the button is useless. If you dig deeper into how tabbed windows work, you will see that there is no main frame window for the tabs, in a group of tabbed windows they seem to be actual windows, just stacked on top of each other and the currently selected tab is the one in front. Here is what it looks like when the X is pressed - "window:" is the top level window returned by `NSApp enumerateWindowsWithOptions:`

```
windowShouldClose: <NSWindow: 0x1007123b0> 
window: <NSWindow: 0x1007123b0> - {{822, 358}, {1024, 856}} - 'OctoShell 2' tabbed window count: 2
  tabbedWindow: <NSWindow: 0x1006160b0> - {{822, 358}, {1024, 856}} - 'OctoShell 1'
  tabbedWindow: <NSWindow: 0x1007123b0> - {{822, 358}, {1024, 856}} - 'OctoShell 2'
```

Here is what it looks like when the red close dot is pressed:

```
windowShouldClose: <NSWindow: 0x10060d2d0>  
window: <NSWindow: 0x100718ac0> - {{822, 358}, {1024, 856}} - 'OctoShell 2' tabbed window count: 2
  tabbedWindow: <NSWindow: 0x10060d2d0> - {{822, 358}, {1024, 856}} - 'OctoShell 1'
  tabbedWindow: <NSWindow: 0x100718ac0> - {{822, 358}, {1024, 856}} - 'OctoShell 2'
```